# Extending Orchard's search/indexing module to search in uploaded Word, Excel, Powerpoint and PDF files

Tags: pdf, indexing, ms-office, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Apparently the following module indexes only content in Orchard sites:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Search-and-indexing

If I upload a DOC, XLS, PPT or PDF file, its content won't be added to the index.

**Is there an out-of-the-box way to include those contents, or do I have to extend the indexing mechanism?**

If the latter is true, any hints are welcome on how to do that. Thank you!

**EDIT:** by 'uploading a file', I mean the standard media upload to the `/Media` folder.

Comment: There is no out of the box way that I know of. I'm not too familiar with how Orchard use Lucene.net to index content, but you can override the default media handling and extract pdf content with ITextSharp. You should then be able to hook into the indexing api and index it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not available out of the box, but possible to implement on your own, especially with upcoming Orchard 1.7 which will make uploaded Media files content items.

There are a few extension points for this, with `OnIndexing<T>` content handler method being the easiest and most straightforward to use. This is the place where extracting keywords and adding them to index should happen. Look at existing implementations for examples.

Speaking of keyword extraction - I used [iTextSharp](https://nuget.org/packages/itextsharp/) for PDFs and [MS OpenXML SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) for handling Office documents (although it will work only for the new formats - DOCX, PPTX and XLSX). For legacy, non-XML Office formats you'd need some other library - there are lots of those on the web.

Comment: IFilters (as used by sharepoint etc) seem quite populate. Supporting those would be a quick route to having multiple types supported

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a link where the change in Media handling in Orchard 1.7 is documented? I downloaded the latest sources and uploaded some Media files, but they don't seem to be handled differently. The ContentTypeRecord table has no entry for Media files: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35614983/orchard_contenttyperecord.png

Comment: Sorry my fault, was on the wrong branch. Here's the link if others are searching for it: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/402143